# How to pass dictionary from Jinja2 (using Python) to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, templates, jinja2

How to pass dictionary from Jinja2 (using Python) to Javascript ?
I have dictionary in Python and when I render template I need to use that dictionary with Javascript, I passed from Python

```
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('sm.html')
self.response.write(template.render(values=values))
```

but how to store them in Javascript variable inside html page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `json` module to turn the Python data into JSON data; JSON is a subset of JavaScript <sup>*</sup> and does fine as a JavaScript literal:

```
import json

js_value = json.dumps(python_value)
```

and render the `js_value` in the template.

If you need the JSON data to be *HTML safe* too, you'll need to add some replacements:

```
js_value = (json.dumps(python_value)
    .replace(u'<', u'\\u003c')
    .replace(u'>', u'\\u003e')
    .replace(u'&', u'\\u0026')
    .replace(u"'", u'\\u0027'))
```

---

<sup>*</sup>JSON allows for [U+2028 and U+2029 characters](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) which JavaScript literals can't contain, but the `json.dumps()` function escapes all non-ASCII codepoints by default, so provided you don't disable `ensure_ascii` you are fine.

Comment: {{ js_value | safe }} seems more convenient

Comment: @LeonF: applying security best practices is not always 'convenient'. `| safe` does not apply *any filtering*, so any non-safe content is passed through into your template.

Comment: @LeonF: in *Flask*, the replacements are taken care of for you when you use the [`tojson` filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-filters). Outside of Flask, you can use the technique in this post to create a similar filter.

Answer (score 1):

You want to store it as [Json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). This is javascript's native format, so you can pass that directly to a variable.